# Making some part of string bold using <span>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to make some part of my string bold. "b" and "strong" tags do not work within the string as "<" part of tag displays in the output for some milliseconds which is quite unprofessional. Please apply solution on my code. I think it might work or please give me some alternate solution. Applying solution on my code will be appreciable. Thanks

```
<pre id="typing"></pre>

<button id="typBt" onclick="startTyping()">Show Typing</button>
<style>
#typBt {
  background-color: green;
  border: 20px solid;
  color: black;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline overline;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 50px 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  outline:none
  
  
}
</style>
<script>

function startTyping(){

  var bt = document.getElementById("typBt");
    bt.style.display = "none";

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  task(i);
}
}
function task(i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Add tasks to do 
    var typeString = ['\u2022 A quick brown fox \r  jumps over the lazy dog. \u2714\uFE0F\n\n\u2022 A quick brown fox \r  jumps over the lazy dog. \u2714\uFE0F\n\n\u2022 A quick broum fox \r  jumnps over the lazy dog. \u2714\uFE0F\n\n\u2022 A quick brown fox \r  jumps over the lazy dog. \u2714\uFE0F\n\n\u2022 A quick brown fox \r  jumps over the lazy dog. \u2714\uFE0F'];
 
    var i = 0;
    var count = 0;
    var selectedText = '';
    var text = '';
    var typing = document.getElementById('typing');
  
    (function type() {
      if (count == typeString.length) {
        count = 0;
      };

      selectedText = typeString[count];
      text = selectedText.slice(0, ++i);
      typing.innerHTML = text.fontsize(3);
      typing.style.fontFamily = "helveticanew";
      typing.style.color = "black";
      typing.style.fontWeight = "normal";
      typing.style.lineHeight = "1"; //Difference between different lines  
      typing.style.textAlign = "left";
      typing.style.margin = "25px";
      
      if (text.length === selectedText.length) {
        count++;
        i = 0;
      }

      /* SOLUTION : wait two seconds when new line */
      if (typeString[0][i - 1] == '\n') {
        setTimeout(type, 1000); //Time delay between two bullets
      } else if (count === 1) {
        setTimeout(type, 5000); //Time delay after typing is finished
      } else {
        setTimeout(type, 40); //Typing speed
      }
    }());
   
  }, 1000);//Start time

  
}


// uni code for bullet "\u2022"
// uni code for tick mark "\u2714\uFE0F"
// line break "\r"
// line break for new bullet "/n"



</script>
```

Comment: Aren’t you going to need to put in some parsing of the string? For example if you find <b> you need to find its terminating </b> and output the text in between one character at a time.

Comment: can you apply this on my code?